# How to fix " table of extent 0 x 2" in R

Tags: r, random-forest

```
RFmodel.rf <- randomForest(Survived ~., data = train, proximity = TRUE, na.action=na.roughfix)

RFmodel.rf

pred <- predict(RFmodel.rf, test, type="class")
head(pred)
summary(pred)

pred <- as.integer(pred>0.5)

table(pred, test$Survived)
```

This comes after I try to create table. and yes I do have Header=TRUE at the start.

> the "table of extent 0 x 2"

My code before this has worked for Logistic regression and for XGboost so I have no idea why its not working for Random forest.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does every line prior to the `table` work? Does `pred` (from the `predict`) hold values that you would expect?

Comment: when I do the first line without na.action=na.roughfix I get the following error -   "Error in na.fail.default(list(Survived = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  : 
  missing values in object" Which is weird because in a previous project everything worked fine.

Comment: This is going to be difficult to offer suggestions without a reproducible example but try and fix the earliest error. Inspect every object to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: Ok cool thank you. After pred <- as.integer(pred>0.5,Im also getting this error In Ops.factor(pred, 0.5) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors. Do you know why this could be? All the pred are turning to NA's.  Ive tried as.numeric but that hasnt worked.

Comment: You are requesting `"class"` be predicted. I'd guess that this returns the predicted **class** with the highest probability -- you could check the help pages. But inspect `pred` after this line: `pred <- predict(RFmodel.rf, test, type="class")`. Does it return a numeric, where `pred>0.5` would make sense or does it return a level / class of the outcome?